# How to get button to line up with div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys I'm trying to achieve this right now: (I would like the button and quantity box to be on the same line)

[image]

However for some reason my button is below my quantiy box and i have no idea why, I'm using bootstrap 3 right now and I've tried to use `col 6` for each and tried `display inline` but no idea how to make it work

html:

```css
.plus-minus-input {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin-left: 136px;
    }
    .plus-minus-input .input-group-field {
     text-align: center;
     width: 50px;
     height: 41px;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 1.2;
     border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
    }
    .plus-minus-input .input-group-field::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .plus-minus-input .input-group-field ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
    }
    .plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle1 {
     border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    .plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle2 {
     border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }
    .btn-primary {
     border-radius: 0px;
     width: 42px;
     height: 41px;
     background-color: #e6e6e6;
     border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
     color: #888888;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn-primary:focus {
     color: #888888;
     background-color: #e6e6e6;
     border-color: #e6e6e6;
     outline: none !important;
     box-shadow: none;
    }
    .btn-danger {
     background-color: #222222;
     border-radius: 23px;
     font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-color: #222222;
     width: 57%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 9px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .btn-danger:hover {
     background-color: #c39d6d;
     border-color: #c39d6d;
    }
```

```html
<div class="input-group plus-minus-input">
       <div class="input-group-button">
        <button class="button hollow circle1 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="minus" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
       </div><input class="input-group-field" name="quantity" type="number" value="0">
       <div class="input-group-button">
        <button class="button hollow circle2 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="plus" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Add to cart</button>
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Use `display: inline-flex` on `plus-minus-input`

Comment: Ok i figured it out, if you put     display: inline-block; on the button and then use display: inline-flex; on quantity it works :)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger beat me 2 it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-flex;` in `.plus-minus-input` class and I have also added `addcart` class in button tag for css like:

```
.addcart {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

```css
.plus-minus-input {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 136px;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-field {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 41px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-field::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .plus-minus-input .input-group-field ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle2 {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-primary {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 42px;
    height: 41px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
    color: #888888;
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #888888;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-danger {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 23px;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #222222;
    width: 57%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.btn-danger:hover {
    background-color: #c39d6d;
    border-color: #c39d6d;
}
.addcart {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group plus-minus-input">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button class="button hollow circle1 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="minus" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <input class="input-group-field" name="quantity" type="number" value="0">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button class="button hollow circle2 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="plus" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="addcart btn btn-danger" type="button">Add to cart</button>
```